# FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed38d61290

Tags: facebook, heroku, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I can't seem to resolve this issue.  I went in and deleted all parse and fb SDKs and then downloaded the newest parse and fb SDKs and put into project.

Still getting this error in logs.  Don't even get to fb screen. Below is my code. I have researched all instances of this issue and yet no resolve. I am missing something.

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import Bolts


// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// import ParseUI

// If you want to use Crash Reporting - uncomment this line
// import ParseCrashReporting

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore. 
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "xxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "xxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/parse"
        })
        
        Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)

        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        
        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true

        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var noPushPayload = false;
            if let options = launchOptions {
                noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }
        
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            
            
           
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }
    
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Push Notifications
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
        
        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded, error) in
            if succeeded {
                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
            }
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
    
    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
            FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }   
}
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

        // array of what we want to get from the fb user account
        let permissions = ["public_profile"]
        
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            
            if let error = error { // if error exists
                
                print(error)
                
            } else {
                
                if let user = user { // if user exists
                    
                    print(user)
                }
            }
        }
    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```